# Lookup values within row in one table using another table

Tags: python, mysql, r, data-structures

I have a table 1 which contains each row in the format :

```
 <ID> <Key1> OR <Key2> OR <Key3> OR <Key4>
```

Another table 2 contains the key value pair in the format :

```
<Key 1> <Value 1>
<Key 2> <Value 2>
```

I want to lookup for each  in table 1 and replace with the corresponding  in table 2. The number of rows in both tables are >30K
What would you recommend is the best way to lookup the data between columns?
The tables reside in Excel, but I am looking for guidance across any tools

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: It would be helpful if you made a few lines of data and also what the desired result it. That said I think you need to pick one "tool" although all the tools you mention will let you do this.

Comment: Why not just VLOOKUP?

Comment: Sorry I missed adding what I tried and have the same detailed below :

Comment: Sorry I missed adding what I tried and have the same detailed below in Excel - Step 1 : Split each row with OR as the delimiter. So now I have each row with one column containing key followed by a blank column. Step 2 : on the blank column next to the key column copy pasted the Vlookup to lookup the key in the other table Step 3: Copy pasted around 2k times got exhausted. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm certainly not an R expert, but an't you just do a split and merge?  Or is that over simplifying things?

```
X <- split(df, df$g)
str(X)


Inner join: merge(df1, df2)

Outer join: merge(x = df1, y = df2, by = "CustomerId", all = TRUE)

Left outer: merge(x = df1, y = df2, by = "CustomerId", all.x = TRUE)

Right outer: merge(x = df1, y = df2, by = "CustomerId", all.y = TRUE)

Cross join: merge(x = df1, y = df2, by = NULL)
```